# How to maintain same code base for multiple deployment platform

Tags: java, web-services

I am working in java project which implements REST API(web services, no micro services or spring boot stuff) which we deploy on multiple application server (Wildfly, Liberty)..So far we have maintained different code base for separate  deployment platform . Inside code though logic is same but import packages and pom dependencies are different . 
Scenario:

1. In Wildfly we are using windows FTP for file transfer, But for liberty server we are using SSL
2. The API which is used to create JWT token in wildfly is not supported in Liberty.

Can anyone suggest a way so that I can create a single code base for different deployment platform and also what are the challenges and bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Spring profiles.

You can create different profiles example (wildfy,liberty) , and create 2 components

```
@Component
@Profile("wildfy")
public class FTPFileTransfer implement FileTransfer

@Component
@Profile("liberty")
public class SSLFileTransfer implement FileTransfer
```

If you start your app  with -Dspring.profiles.active=wildfy, you have a specific implementation for FileTransfer.

I suggest you to read the spring documentation on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles.

Comment: Link only answers (or close-to-link-only-answers) are discouraged because the can suffer from link-rot. Please include at least a short abstract in your answer.

Comment: The problem is with dependencies ...If i keep all the jars together and make war , the war doesn't get deployed properly since Liberty does not support apache packages, and wildfly doesnt use liberty packages...

Comment: you can use a maven profile for add dependencies or not